# ng-hide expression not working with and and null conditions

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I am trying to implement a statement that will hide the hello world. I have tried adding the expression to a function in typescript but it still would not hide it.

```
<div ng-hide="textformField.DefaultValueQuery == null && textformField.PlaceHolderQuery == null"> Hello World
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ng-hide` is angularjs (1.x) directive, it won;t working with Angular (2+) version. Instead use `*ngIf` directive. `ngIf` directive `add`/`remove` a DOM from DOM tree when expression evaluated to `true`/`false`.

```
<div *ngIf="textformField.DefaultValueQuery == null && textformField.PlaceHolderQuery == null">
  Hello World
</div>
```